# Does the "truncation function" $\langle a,b\rangle : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ have an accepted name or notation?

Tags: real-analysis, notation, terminology, mathematical-modeling, applications

Given real numbers $a$ and $b$ satisfying $a \leq b$, define:

$$\langle a,b\rangle (x) = \mathrm{min}(b,\mathrm{max}(a,x)) = \mathrm{max}(a,\mathrm{min}(b,x))$$

(These numbers are equal because $a \leq b$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_lattice) for some relevant abstract generalities.)

So basically, the function $$\langle a,b\rangle : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ has the effect of "truncating" a real number so as to lie in the interval $[a,b]$.

This function shows up implicitly in one of my applied math homework assignments. We're modelling the amount of fluid in a reservoir; due to rainfall or evaporation, the volume changes, but it always remains between $0$ and $V_\mathrm{max}$, and hence the function $\langle 0,V_\mathrm{max}\rangle$ implicitly shows up in our numerical model.

I'll bet the function $\langle a,b\rangle$ shows up all over applied math, so:

> **Question.** Does this function have an accepted name or notation?

Comment: In programming, we usually call that a "constrain" function. I have never seen such a function in mathematical texts. Usually, a mathematician will simply state that $x$ lies on the interval $[a,b]$. Mathematics is less structured than programming, so we don't need functions for everything.

Comment: @pseudoeuclidean, I don't much like that style of mathematics in which the author(s) can't be bothered to make explicit the functions they're implicitly using. It's low quality, and deserves our criticism.

Comment: My mathematics teachers have always told me, "mathematicians are the laziest people alive". My teachers would agree with you. However, implicitly defining a problem is often less restrictive in a way. It frees the mind to think about the problem in any way that you'd like, without a strict, explicitly defined structure.

Comment: @pseudoeuclidean, I can agree with that. I'm not averse to mixing in a bit of vague "premathematics" into the actual math e.g. to help the reader get onto the same page as you. But we shouldn't *leave* it at that, despite that this is so often done.